# An efficient way of using getElementByID multiple times with Object literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, getelementbyid

I'm a beginner at javascript and just getting started with working with the DOM. After grabbing a bunch of spans with different ID names at several different places and grabbing the data from an object literal, it seemed to start getting redundant. Isn't there a better way of writing this? I'm also learning functions but not really sure how to relate it together. Here's the JSfiddle for easier viewing. https://jsfiddle.net/q5366wzb/

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="candidates">
   <legend>Candidates</legend>
   <div>
   <label for="cand1">Candidate 1</label>
   <span class="candidate" id="cand1"></span>
   <span class="party" id="party1"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="cand2">Candidate 2</label>
  <span class="candidate" id="cand2"></span>
  <span class="party" id="party2"></span>
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="cand3">Candidate 3</label>
  <span class="candidate" id="cand3"></span>
  <span class="party" id="party3"></span>
 </div>
 </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="statistics">
  <div>
  <h2>Results for Candidate 1</h2>
   <div id="candidateName1"></div>
   <label for="cand1pct">Percentage</label>
   <output id="cand1pct"></output>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h2>Results for Candidate 2</h2>
  <div id="candidateName2"></div>
  <label for="cand2pct">Percentage</label>
  <output id="cand2pct"></output>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h2>Results for Candidate 3</h2>
  <div id="candidateName3"></div>
  <label for="cand3pct">Percentage</label>
  <output id="cand3pct"></output>
  </div>
  </fieldset>
```

JS

```
var votingData = {
  candidates: [{
  name: "Harry S. Truman",
  party: "Democratic"
},
{
  name: "Thomas E. Dewey",
  party: "Republican"
},
{
  name: "Strom Thurmond",
  party: "Dixiecrat"
}]
};


 document.getElementById("cand1").innerHTML = 
 votingData.candidates[0].name;
 document.getElementById("candidateName1").innerHTML = 
 votingData.candidates[0].name;
 document.getElementById("party1").innerHTML = 
 votingData.candidates[0].party;

 document.getElementById("cand2").innerHTML = 
 votingData.candidates[1].name;
 document.getElementById("candidateName2").innerHTML = 
 votingData.candidates[1].name;
 document.getElementById("party2").innerHTML = 
 votingData.candidates[1].party;

 document.getElementById("cand3").innerHTML = 
 votingData.candidates[2].name;
 document.getElementById("candidateName3").innerHTML = 
 votingData.candidates[2].name;
 document.getElementById("party3").innerHTML = 
 votingData.candidates[2].party;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looping over the `candidates`
array inside the `votingData`
object you can have the loop which iterates over the array and reduce the amount of duplication.

```js
var votingData = {
  candidates: [{
    name: "Harry S. Truman",
    party: "Democratic"
  }, {
    name: "Thomas E. Dewey",
    party: "Republican"
  }, {
    name: "Strom Thurmond",
    party: "Dixiecrat"
  }]
};

var candidates = votingData.candidates;

for (var i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
  var currentId = i + 1;
  document.getElementById("cand" + currentId).innerHTML = candidates[i].name;
  document.getElementById("candidateName" + currentId).innerHTML = candidates[i].name;
  document.getElementById("party" + currentId).innerHTML = candidates[i].party;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="candidates">
  <legend>Candidates</legend>
  <div>
<label for="cand1">Candidate 1</label>
<span class="candidate" id="cand1"></span>
<span class="party" id="party1"></span>
  </div>

  <div>
<label for="cand2">Candidate 2</label>
<span class="candidate" id="cand2"></span>
<span class="party" id="party2"></span>
  </div>

  <div>
<label for="cand3">Candidate 3</label>
<span class="candidate" id="cand3"></span>
<span class="party" id="party3"></span>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="statistics">
  <div>
<h2>Results for Candidate 1</h2>
<div id="candidateName1"></div>
<label for="cand1pct">Percentage</label>
<output id="cand1pct"></output>
  </div>
  <div>
<h2>Results for Candidate 2</h2>
<div id="candidateName2"></div>
<label for="cand2pct">Percentage</label>
<output id="cand2pct"></output>
  </div>
  <div>
<h2>Results for Candidate 3</h2>
<div id="candidateName3"></div>
<label for="cand3pct">Percentage</label>
<output id="cand3pct"></output>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I fully understand this, you created a new variable, which then accesses the object with dot notation to the candidate property. Then using a for loop, from candidates length, so that would be three? or 1? Then created a new variable that takes EACH candidate array? which then takes each candidate to each proper placement?

Comment: @BeckyT The length will be 3, since `votingData.candidates` relates to the array which has 3 items. All the other statements that you made are correct.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. Getting there.

Comment: @BeckyT Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to not use id names with added numbers like candidateName1, candidateName2 and candidateName3, but replace it with a class that you can reuse, like candidate (simplified example):

```
<fieldset id="statistics">
  <div>
  <h2>Results for Candidate 1</h2>
   <div class="candidate"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div class="candidate"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div class="candidate"></div>
  </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Then you can select it in one go:

```
var candidates = document.getElementsByClassName('candidate');
```

Then you iterate via a for loop (you can apply the other elements as well here):

```
for (var i = 0, n = votingData.candidates.length; i < n; i++) {
    candidates.innerHTML = votingData.candidates[i];
}
```